# Sorting bibliography by title with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

How would I sort by title using biblatex?
I'm writing in Arabic with the package xepersian.

Answer (score 4):

Simply define your own sorting scheme that sorts how you want, something like this in your preamble (see the documentation for `\DeclareSortingScheme` in the manual):

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{tyn}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}
```

and then add the global option `sorting=tyn` to your load options:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=tyn]{biblatex}
```