# Customize bibliography separating different kinds of entries and joining them by same title

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, biber, custom-bib

I am making an article in which I am not making citations within the text, but I want to print a bunch of bibliography at the end.

I have different kinds of entries, like "article", "thesis", and "miscellanea", and I want to print them separately, in reverse chronological order, and joining entries with the same name.

I have 0 experience customizing bibliography, and so far I am using default styles.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{989898}
\colorlet{textcolor}{lightgray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometry %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip}

\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2011,
    author = {Doe, John},
    journal = {Nucleic Acids Research},
    pages = {1--3},
    title = {{Title of paper}},
    volume = {39},
    year = {2011}
}
@article{Smith2013,
    author = {Smith, Josh},
    journal = {Nature},
    pages = {1--6},
    title = {{Overly complicated title}},
    volume = {85},
    year = {2013}
}
@article{Adams2016,
    author = {Adams, Brian},
    journal = {Science},
    pages = {10--15},
    title = {{Another absurd title}},
    volume = {2},
    year = {2016}
}
@phdthesis{Surname2012,
    author = {Surname, Name},
    location = {Some University},
    title = {{Some suitable thesis name}},
    type = {PhD Thesis},
    url = {http://thesis},
    year = {2012}
}
@misc{Willis2013,
    location = {Some Uni},
    note = {Work In Progress report},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{This is the same title always}},
    type = {TALK},
    month = {07},
    year = {2013}
}
@misc{Willis2014,
    location = {Another Uni},
    note = {Poster Symposium},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{This is the same title always}},
    type = {POSTER},
    month = {09},
    year = {2014}
}
@misc{Willis2014b,
    location = {Yet Another Uni},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{This is the same title always}},
    type = {TALK},
    month = {09},
    year = {2014}
}
@misc{Willis2015,
    location = {Research Center},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{New title}},
    type = {TALK},
    month = {09},
    year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following with Biber (the final result doesn't have to be with Biber):

[image: fig1]

I would like to mimic the following result I produced with LibreOffice Writer, and I was wondering which would be the best way to obtain it, if it's possible.

[image: fig2]

Many, many thanks!!

**EDIT**

**Based on @Bernard answer and borrowing code from my old Friggeri's CV (now broken), the following is my best shot at it (not absolutely sure what I'm doing, just coping and pasting things that seem to work, so please if you spot anything wrong, let me know).**

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{989898}
\colorlet{textcolor}{lightgray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometry %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Doe2011,
        author = {Doe, John},
        journal = {Nucleic Acids Research},
        pages = {1--3},
        title = {{Title of paper}},
        volume = {39},
        year = {2011}
    }
    @article{Smith2013,
        author = {Smith, Josh},
        journal = {Nature},
        pages = {1--6},
        title = {{Overly complicated title}},
        volume = {85},
        year = {2013}
    }
    @article{Adams2016,
        author = {Adams, Brian},
        journal = {Science},
        pages = {10--15},
        title = {{Another absurd title}},
        volume = {2},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @phdthesis{Surname2012,
        author = {Surname, Name},
        location = {Some University},
        title = {{Some suitable thesis name}},
        type = {PhD Thesis},
        url = {http://thesis},
        year = {2012}
    }
    @misc{Willis2013,
        location = {Some Uni},
        note = {Work In Progress report},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {TALK},
        month = {07},
        year = {2013}
    }
    @misc{Willis2014,
        location = {Another Uni},
        note = {Poster Symposium},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {POSTER},
        month = {03},
        year = {2014}
    }
    @misc{Willis2014b,
        location = {Yet Another Uni},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {TALK},
        day = {12}, %I include the day in entries in the same month and year
        month = {09},
        year = {2014}
    }
    @misc{Willis2014c,
        location = {Research Center},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {TALK},
        day = {25}, %I include the day in entries in the same month and year
        month = {09},
        year = {2014}
    }
    @misc{Willis2016,
        location = {Another Research Center},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{New title}},
        type = {TALK},
        month = {09},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage[style=verbose, defernumbers=true, sorting=tyn, backend=biber, dateabbrev=true]{biblatex}%


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


%%SORTING

\DeclareSortingScheme{tyn}{
    \sort{
        \field{presort}
    }
    \sort[final]{
        \field{sortkey}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sortyear}
        \field{year}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sortname}
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
        \field{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{volume}
        \literal{0}
    }
}


%%ARTICLE

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \textbf{\printfield{title}}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    \printnames{author}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    {%
        \small \addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \itshape%
        \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
        \setunit{\space}%
        \printfield{pages}%
        \newunit%
        \printlist{publisher}%
        %\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        %\printfield{year}%included in issuetitle
        \newunit%
    }
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
}


%%THESIS

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
    \textbf{\printfield{title}}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    \printnames{author}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    {%
        \small \addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \itshape%
        \printfield{type}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \printfield{url}%
        \newunit%
    }
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}
}

%%MISCELLANEA

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\\}

\newbibmacro*{bib:svtitle}{%
    \savefield{title}{\lasttitle}}

\newbibmacro*{bib:svauthor}{%
    \savename{author}{\lastauthor}}

\newbibmacro*{verifytitle}{%
    \iffieldequals{title}{\lasttitle}{\hspace{\bibhang}}{%
        \printfield{title}%
        \undef\lastauthor}%
    \usebibmacro{bib:svtitle}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\adddot\finentry}

\newbibmacro*{verifyauthor}{%
    \ifnameequals{author}{\lastauthor}
    {}
    {\printnames{author}\\}%
    \usebibmacro{bib:svauthor}}

\newbibmacro*{newtitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{verifytitle}}

\newbibmacro*{newauthor}{%
    \usebibmacro{verifyauthor}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
    \textbf{\usebibmacro{newtitle}}%
    \usebibmacro{newauthor}%
    {%
        \scriptsize \textcolor{lightgray}{\faCaretRight}%
    }
    {%
        \footnotesize \addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \itshape%
        \hspace{5px}%
        \printfield{type} (\printfield{month} \printfield{year})%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \printfield{note}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printlist{location}%
    }
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}






\newcommand{\printbibsection}[1]{
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type={#1}, heading=none]
    \end{refsection}
}






\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \medskip

    \section{Print articles here:}
    \printbibsection{article}

    \section{Print thesis here:}
    \printbibsection{thesis}

    \section{Print miscellanea here:}
    \printbibsection{misc}

\end{document}
```

**Which produces the following:**

[image: fig3]

**While the articles and thesis seem to be printed correctly and in the proper order (it will probably need more testing), there are still some obvious mistakes in the miscellanea section.**

**Here I joined entries with the same title, but the name should appear for the second set of entries as well... Besides, the ordering is off, I would need more recent entries above, same as with the articles. To stress this, I included an additional entry, in the same month and year, but different day (cause I know I do have these cases in my real document), so the sorting should be reverse chronological, including year, month, and day.**

**Any ideas here? We are almost there!**

Comment: That is not a small task. You need to do two main things: (1) Create an appropriate `.bbx` that controls the formatting of your bibliography (the complexity of this will depend on how many different entry types you need to cater to and how complex the bibliographical data is that you need to present); (2) ensure that the style with 'entry sets' (`@set`).  Then all you need to do is `\printbibliography` in some sort of discriminating way (e.g., by `type`).

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your comment... yeah it sounds difficult and I really don't know where to start, but luckily it's only those 3 types of entries that I will be dealing with (article, phdthesis, misc [of subtype TALK and POSTER, which don't really matter])... anything in mind?

Comment: Please check the edit. It's almost there!

Comment: I'm afraid I have no time to look at anything in detail right now, but look at your `sorting=tyn`. If you want a different sorting order, `biblatex` includes lots of options (see the manual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does 95% of what was originally requested, but it fails for some reason to sort by day entries from same year and month (the TALK at "Research Center" was on the 25/09/2014, so should be listed ABOVE the TALK at "Yet Another Uni" on the 12/09/2014).

Another thing I would like to fix would be the color of the period at the end of the Miscellanea entries (notice it is black - the color of the text - instead of lightgray).

I will open a new question for these 2 little problems.

In the meantime, the current code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{textcolor}{black}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometry %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Doe2011,
        author = {Doe, John},
        journal = {Nucleic Acids Research},
        pages = {1--3},
        title = {{Title of paper}},
        volume = {39},
        year = {2011}
    }
    @article{Smith2013,
        author = {Smith, Josh},
        journal = {Nature},
        pages = {1--6},
        title = {{Overly complicated title}},
        volume = {85},
        year = {2013}
    }
    @article{Adams2016,
        author = {Adams, Brian},
        journal = {Science},
        pages = {10--15},
        title = {{Another absurd title}},
        volume = {2},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @phdthesis{Surname2012,
        author = {Surname, Name},
        location = {Some University},
        title = {{Some suitable thesis name}},
        type = {PhD Thesis},
        url = {http://thesis},
        year = {2012}
    }
    @misc{Willis2013,
        location = {Some Uni},
        note = {Work In Progress report},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {TALK},
        month = {07},
        year = {2013}
    }
    @misc{Willis2014,
        location = {Another Uni},
        note = {Poster Symposium},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {POSTER},
        month = {03},
        year = {2014}
    }
    @misc{Willis2014b,
        location = {Yet Another Uni},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {TALK},
        day = {12}, %I include the day in entries in the same month and year
        month = {09},
        year = {2014}
    }
    @misc{Willis2014c,
        location = {Research Center},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{This is the same title always}},
        type = {TALK},
        day = {25}, %I include the day in entries in the same month and year
        month = {09},
        year = {2014}
    }
    @misc{Willis2016,
        location = {Another Research Center},
        author = {Willis, William},
        title = {{New title}},
        type = {TALK},
        month = {09},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}




\usepackage[style=verbose, defernumbers=true, sorting=ymdnt, backend=biber, dateabbrev=true, maxbibnames=7, minbibnames=7]{biblatex}%

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{first-last}

%%SORTING

\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdnt}{
    \sort{
        \field{presort}
    }
    \sort[final]{
        \field{sortkey}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
        \literal{9999}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
        \literal{00}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
        \literal{00}
    }
    \sort{
        \name{sortname}
        \name{author}
        \name{editor}
        \name{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
}

%%ARTICLE

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \printfield{title}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    \printnames{author}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    {%
        \small \addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \itshape%
        \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
        \setunit{\space}%
        \printfield{pages}%
        \newunit%
        \printfield{url}%
    }
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
}

%%THESIS

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
    \printfield{title}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    \printnames{author}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    {%
        \small \addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \itshape%
        \printfield{type}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \printfield{pages}%
        \newunit%
        \printfield{url}%
    }
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}
}

%%MISCELLANEA

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\\}

\newbibmacro*{bib:svtitle}{%
    \savefield{title}{\lasttitle}}

\newbibmacro*{bib:svauthor}{%
    \savename{author}{\lastauthor}}

\newbibmacro*{verifytitle}{%
    \iffieldequals{title}{\lasttitle}{\hspace{\bibhang}}{%
        \printfield{title}%
        \undef\lastauthor}%
    \usebibmacro{bib:svtitle}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\adddot\finentry}

\newbibmacro*{verifyauthor}{%
    \ifnameequals{author}{\lastauthor}
    {}
    {\printnames{author}\\}%
    \usebibmacro{bib:svauthor}}

\newbibmacro*{newtitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{verifytitle}}

\newbibmacro*{newauthor}{%
    \usebibmacro{verifyauthor}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
    \usebibmacro{newtitle}%
    \usebibmacro{newauthor}%
    {%
        \scriptsize \textcolor{lightgray}{\faCaretRight}%
    }
    {%
        \footnotesize \addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \itshape%
        \hspace{5px}%
        \printfield{type} (\printfield{month} \printfield{year})%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \printfield{note}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printlist{location}%
    }
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[1]{
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type={#1}, heading=none]
    \end{refsection}
}





\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \medskip

    \section{Articles}
    \printbibsection{article}

    \section{Thesis}
    \printbibsection{thesis}

    \section{Miscellanea}
    \printbibsection{misc}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: fig]

Comment: follow it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342801/biblatex-1-change-the-color-of-the-period-at-the-end-2-why-doesnt-day-sort

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution, with `xpatch` and borrowing a `tyn` sorting scheme from  the answer to  a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333815/sorting-bibliography-by-title-with-biblatex/333873#333873) on this site. I considered only the entry types used in the question and didn't check if there are any side-effects.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{989898}
\colorlet{textcolor}{lightgray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometry %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2011,
    author = {Doe, John},
    journal = {Nucleic Acids Research},
    pages = {1--3},
    title = {{Title of paper}},
    volume = {39},
    year = {2011}
}
@article{Smith2013,
    author = {Smith, Josh},
    journal = {Nature},
    pages = {1--6},
    title = {{Overly complicated title}},
    volume = {85},
    year = {2013}
}
@article{Adams2016,
    author = {Adams, Brian},
    journal = {Science},
    pages = {10--15},
    title = {{Another absurd title}},
    volume = {2},
    year = {2016}
}
@thesis{Surname2012,
    author = {Surname, Name},
    location = {Some University},
    title = {{Some suitable thesis name}},
    url = {http://thesis},
    year = {2012}
}
@misc{Willis2013,
    location = {Some Uni},
    note = {Work In Progress report},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{This is the same title always}},
    type = {TALK},
    month = {07},
    year = {2013}
}
@misc{Willis2014,
    location = {Another Uni},
    note = {Poster Symposium},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{This is the same title always}},
    type = {POSTER},
    month = {09},
    year = {2014}
}
@misc{Willis2014b,
    location = {Yet Another Uni},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{This is the same title always}},
    type = {TALK},
    month = {09},
    year = {2014}
}
@misc{Willis2015,
    location = {Research Center},
    author = {Willis, William},
    title = {{New title}},
    type = {TALK},
    month = {09},
    year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}%
 \usepackage[bibstyle=authortitle, defernumbers=true, sorting=tyn]{biblatex}%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingScheme{tyn}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\\}
\DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\char"25BA\addspace\addthinspace\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished, misc]
  {title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{%
\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}}
{}{}{}
%%
    \xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
    }{%
  \usebibmacro{title}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
    }{}{}
    %%
    \xpatchbibdriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
    }{%
  \usebibmacro{title}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
}{}{}
    %%
    \xpatchbibdriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
    }{%
  \usebibmacro{title}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
    }{}{}
\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \nocite{*}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subbibliography,
title={\bfseries Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=thesis, heading=subbibliography,
title={\bfseries Thesis}]
\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibliography,
title={\bfseries Other}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard! Many many thanks for your answer; it seems we are getting somewhere here, but I still find some major problems. For some reason, when I run your code, I get the Author Name first, and then the Title indented and in bold face... On another hand, the sorting of the Other section seems a little bit messy (July 2013 before Sept 2014, instead of after). And last thing: How can I not print the words "References", "Articles", "Thesis" and "Other" at all? I want to print those within the body of the text, as sections.

Comment: Please check my edit with a new MWE based on your answer! We are almost there! Thanks

Comment: @DaniCee: Yes, I see I forgot to add the driver patches. It's fixed now. It's shorter than what you did, but, of course, as this is a major change, your way is the right way to define what might be called an `titleauthor` style (as opposed to `authortitle`). I'll take look at your other modifications tomorrow.

Comment: Many thanks @Bernard, let me know as soon as you have an update on it, I'm stuck!

Comment: I finally got it! Will update later

Comment: Fine! :o) I didn't have time to delve into the problem yet. I'd very  much like to see your solution!

Comment: I just copied code from different places, so might be a little bit ugly, feel free to clean it up!